# MVC Stored procedure calling

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, stored-procedures

Since this question created a lot of confusion let me put in this way :

I am working on an MVC C# project with Entity Framework. I am using a web service to implement a billing feature. Here I am passing values like this:

```
  Billing.cost bills = new Billing.cost();
  bills.Charge(0,"model",8,0,"Date",0,1,1,1,0,0,"N","APP","myemail",1,"cost");
```

Here in place of a model I need to pass my stored procedure name which has required values. My complete code with Stored procedure :

```
using (var ctx = new market_Entities())
        {
           ctx.uspmodel(10);
           ctx.SaveChanges();
           Billing.cost bills = new Billing.cost();
           bills.Charge(0,"ctx",8,0,"Date",0,1,1,1,0,0,"N","APP","myemail",1,"cost");

        }
```

Here 10 is an ID which i am passing as an input parameter. In **charge** method, 2nd parameter that is **ctx** is of string type and it is reference to my SP.

Problem I have is :

1) My stored procedure doesn't have output parameter.It is taking **id** as input parameter and based on that it is selecting **name**, **value** and **address**. So in place of **ctx**, I need to pass **address** result which I am getting from my stored procedure. But how can I select only particular property from market_entities and pass it as parameter ?

2) when I put breakpoints and check for results, I am not able to see any results.So how can i check results for a stored procedure in MVC which doesn't have output parameters?

Comment: "Infact i am writing this from php to MVC" -is that true?? plz adjust your tags..

Comment: This doesn't make sense, you shouldn't need to pass around "column" names. EF is an ORM and therefore all the relevant columns (by default) will be mapped to properties on the class i.e. `bills.ColumnName = "value"`

Comment: @James can you just have a look into my question now. I changed it to make it more clear..